# Editor specific command state

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created a command and a handler that interacts with text editors (objects implementing `ITextEditor`). For each editor that the handler interacts with I'd like to store some data that the handler has access to.

What is the best way to do this?

### Information about my specific problem

My command modifies the selection of text of the active editor. When the command is executed I want to store information about the previous selection. Another command should be able read this information and restore the previous selection.

### Thoughts and observations

- If one handler instance was created for each editor that would solve my problem. Is there a way to achieve this?
- I've looked at the [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/JavaEditor.java) of the Java editor, trying to understand how things work there. The editor stores references to action objects. Since I can't create new fields for my command I can't use the same approach.
- I've [looked at](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/15/toggling-a-command-contribution/) the `<state>` `plugin.xml` tag, but I don't understand how to get one piece of state for each editor. But maybe there is a way?
- I could manually maintain a map from editor to state object, and maybe register a listener for when editors are opened and closed. But I would prefer if there was a simpler way, where I didn't have to do this myself.
- Maybe actions (`IAction`) could be used? But aren't they an old mechanism that has been substituted by commands?
- I could maybe manually set an `IAction` object which as an reference to the stack using the `ITextEditor.setAction`.

Comment: For Eclipse 4 you could perhaps use the MPart transient data (this can be accessed even for 3.x compatibility mode editors). Otherwise I think a Map is probably required. The old IAction interface doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse 4 you could use the transient data of the `MPart` object associated with the `IEditorPart`.

To get the `MPart` from an `IEditorPart` use:

```java
MPart part = editor.getSite().getService(MPart.class);

Map<String, Object> transientData = part.getTransientData();
```

You can store anything you like in the transient data, use a key unique to your handler for the map key. The data is discarded when the editor closes.